Movie where man is in love with dream girl, sleeps all the time
I can't seem to find a movie I once saw years ago. In the movie there was a guy who met a girl in his dreams. After a while he started to sleep more and more, sometimes even during daytime just to spend more time with her.
He even redesigned his flat to be sound proof and dark to help him sleep undisturbed.
His dream relationship eventually put a strain on his real life...
I don't really remember how the movie ended, but I hope someone can figure out the name of the movie.

The Good Night
Here is the relevant bit from the synopsis on IMDB:

Gary is feeling depressed and dejected... until he meets Anna. She's glamorous and smart; she's seductive and witty. Best of all, she's crazy about Gary. Anna is the girl of Gary's dreams...literally. And that's the problem. Gary can only see Anna in his dream life, so he's got to find a way to carry on the most satisfying relationship of his life, in his dreams. His quest for lucid dreaming techniques introduces Gary to some crazy characters who ultimately give him a new perspective on life.

The reason why he sound proofs and blacks out his room is because he was told this helps with lucid dreaming. The strain in his real life is a combination of his friends thinking he is crazy, and him dedicating more and more time to sleeping like you said. 
Here is a spoiler from the ending:

Eventually he sees the girl on a bus billboard, and gets his friend to introduce him to the girl. In his dream the girl acts very different than real life which causes problems because he keeps trying to coach the girl to act like his dream version.

